# Windows Service sending Toast Notification

Tags: c#, windows, notifications

I'm trying to make a Windows Service on my Windows 10 machine. I want it to periodically create a Toast Notification, but I am having a lot of trouble:

It appears that these notifications are in the `Windows.UI.Notifications` namespace ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.aspx)). But not a single namespace starting with Windows is accessible, and I can't add `Windows.winmd` as a reference to get them.

As far as I know Toast Notifications are supposed to be accessible not just for Windows 10 but also for Windows 8. Does this apply for making services? Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Currently I am going to make a separate app that gets invoked just to send a notification, but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add in the `.csproj` the following line :

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

I don't know if it has a required place, but I always put mine in the `<PropertyGroup/>` where `<TargetFrameworkVersion/>` is.

After that, you will need be able to add the references (they will be under a "Windows" tab).

Comment: Thanks! Worked great for getting the references in. For those who are seeing this later, it does not allow you to use the ToastNotifications just from this, it looks more complicated and I'm still working on a solution.